# Why am I unable to properly combine these figures?

Tags: octave

I have a long list of figures that plot the same two lines of data, but each figure only contains a small portion of the domain. I want to combine them all into a single graph. I've done this before with similar figures with no issues, but I've been unable to properly combine these. [Here is an example of two of the individual figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoBIG.png)

This is an example of a method that seems to work for re-plotting similar figures, here I attempt to plot the data from on of the two figures I attached an image of onto a new figure:

```
figA = openfig('figuredirectory');
axA = gca;
fig = figure;
s1 = subplot(1,1,1);
figA = get(axA, 'children');
copyobj(figA,s1);`
```

Instead of producing the same figure however, it produces this: [Image of the produced figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q13Pr.png)

Another example that produces an incorrect result is:

```
figA = openfig('figuredirectory');
axA = gca;
fig = figure;
copyobj(axA,fig);
```

Where I'm left with an empty figure. [Image of the empty figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INI6s.png)

I'm fairly inexperienced with MatLab, so it's very likely that I'm missing something obvious. I've attached dropbox links to two of the figures if it's of any help. [Fig1](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/q11d35k34nrb4l7wbiezs/I2TESTAFig1.ofig?rlkey=4elu10ue3escs2s4ekbx16pvy&dl=0) [Fig2](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zs87nh5zs4ewb6ktzjgkv/I2TESTBFig1.ofig?rlkey=2t7pju7dce0wnr39mtk8cvr9x&dl=0)

Comment: Well, in the second case you copy the children of an axes object into a figure object. You need to put them into a new axes object instead. For the first case, it might be related to the axes limits. You copy the axes children, but not its other properties.

Comment: Actually, maybe you are copying the legend, which is an axes of its own.

Comment: Yes may be the last active `axes` in the figure was the legend and this is what you are copying in exemple 2. Note: I cannot open the figure files you linked with MATLAB, the figure files are **Octave** figures. You should definitely include this information when asking such questions.

Comment: as @Hoki said, you said Matlab in your post but tagged Octave.  you should stick to one or the other unless you are specifically asking about something related to both (compatibility, etc).  in this case, you should probably just refer to Octave, since you are using Octave figures.